# generate a PDF from a form bonitasoft

Tags: forms, pdf-generation, screenshot, export-to-pdf, bonita

Under my Project of end of studies I work with the Bonitasoft Community Edition version 6.4.1 tool I am requested to achieve an "Export as PDF" button in my form which will export this form and its data (such as a screen shot of the web page displayed in the browser) in order to print it and send it via mail

Comment: So what's not working for you?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Questions here are supposed to show your own coding effort. This is not a question and looks much more like a "please code this for me" request, which are not welcome on SO.

Comment: in fact i'm not asking for giving me a code to paste ! i'm asking for helpful ideas as a support , i'm still a beginner with bonitasoft and the Community edition lucks so many options (the option of generating a file from a form is available in sbscription edition)

Comment: I would say that this kind of question is better for Bonitasoft Community website than for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag on you button on the button actions tab.

Embed a java library who will do this task, with a function accepting 
processApi (ProcessRuntimeAPI) and processInstanceId as parameters.

You can then retrieve your process variables with the Boniatsoft api

```
processApi.getProcessDataInstances(processInstanceId, 0, 10000);
```

The remaining task is to inject thoses variables in your report server.

And to call this function from a groovy script **after** form posting, in the task connectors.